# ESP32 runtime error in 2d array

Tags: serial, esp32, array

I am trying to serial print the value of `b[0][0]`.

Has to be zero but it dose not work!

**Here is the code**

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  byte b[321][241];
  Serial.println(b[0][0]);
}

void loop() {

}
```

If the array is small like `b[2][2]` it dose work

In theory esp32 has ram of  ‎520 KiB SRAM so can this be a problem?

**Here is the error code**

```
rst:0x8 (TG1WDT_SYS_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1216
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40078000,len:9720
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40080400,len:6352
entry 0x400806b8
```

The code complies fine but the error gets when esp32 is running

esp32 version for arduino is 1.0.4

Comment: what about b[2][241] or b[321][2] ?

Comment: Stack size is usually much smaller than RAM, especially if it's running under RTOS, so I'd expect problems with it.

Comment: @jsotola for b[321][2] I get the value 165 as output shouldn't it be zero also for b[2][241] is 165

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ESP32 uses FreeRTOS to run everything, and that includes the Arduino API. Your code is running in a thread of its own ("loopTask"), and that task by default has 8192 bytes of stack allocated to it.

```
xTaskCreateUniversal(loopTask, "loopTask", 8192, NULL, 1, &loopTaskHandle, CONFIG_ARDUINO_RUNNING_CORE);
```

You cannot create local variables and other stack data that totals more than 8192 bytes.

Instead you will either have to have the variable as a global variable (or static local) so it gets allocated in the global data segment, or use `new` or `malloc` to create it on the heap (and don't forget the corresponding `delete` or `free` call when you're done with it).

Comment: creating the variable as global seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This may be due to serial buffer size.
ESP32 may wrire new data before finshing previous transfer. Add a delay after print line and see.

Comment: nop that did not work